# Constructing Tensorflow Dataset and applying TextVectorization layer using map method

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, nlp

I'm attempting to construct input to an embedding layer for an NLP model. However, I am having problems with converting raw text data to the numerical input required by the embedding layer.

Here is some example data to illustrate what I wish to feed to the NLP model:

```
# 0 = negative
# 1 = positive
documents = [['topology freaking sucks man, what a waste of time!', 0], ['wow bro you a NLP fan? Tell me more I want to know', 1], 
['you know, I will eventually die',0], ['the secret to happiness is to only be depresssed',0], 
['what is the floor without feet', 1], ['regicide is permissable only in historical situations',1],
['I do not like delivering wehat based products for I am allergic to wheat', 0], 
['Why does he ring the large bell every hour?',0],
['Wisdom comes not from experience but from knowing',1], 
['Little is known of the inner workings of the feline mind', 1]]
```

Each document contains one sentence and one label. This data format was inspired by the tutorial prompt I am working on:

> Your Task
> Your task in this lesson is to design a small document classification problem with 10 documents of one sentence each and associated labels of positive and negative outcomes and to train a network with word embedding on these data.

I utilize the TextVectorization function from the keras library:

```
# create preprocessing layer
VOCAB_SIZE = 500 # max amount of vocabulary amongst all documents
MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH = 50 # maximum amount of words/tokens that will be considered in each document
# output mode 'int' will assign unique integer per token, so in our example below, 'topology' is assigned the value
# 19. Notice that these integers are randomly assigned and essentially acts as a hashmap
int_vectorize_layer = TextVectorization(
    max_tokens=VOCAB_SIZE,
    output_mode='int',
    output_sequence_length = MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH
)
```

The issue now becomes applying this vectorized layer to the raw data `documents`. Here is the following code I have to convert the raw data into a tensorflow `Dataset` object:

```
# Applies adapted layer to tensorflow dataset
def int_vectorize_text(sentence, label):
  sentence = tf.expand_dims(sentence, -1)
  sentence = tf.squeeze(sentence, axis=-1)
  return int_vectorize_layer(sentence), label


# passes raw data as a generator to the Dataset from_generator constructor
def generate_data(sentences, labels):
  for s, l in zip(sentences,labels):
    yield s, l

# split raw data between training and validation set
train_docs = documents[:8]
val_docs = documents[8:]

# separate sentences and labels
train_sentences = [d[0] for d in train_docs]
train_labels = [d[1] for d in train_docs]

val_sentences = [d[0] for d in val_docs]
val_labels = [d[1] for d in val_docs]

# convert to tensors
train_sentences_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(train_sentences)
train_labels_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(train_labels)

val_sentences_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(val_sentences)
val_labels_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(val_labels)

# build tensorflow Dataset using the above generator function on the newly constructed tensor objects
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    generate_data, (tf.string, tf.int32), args=(train_sentences_tensor, train_labels_tensor))
val_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    generate_data, (tf.string, tf.int32), args=(val_sentences_tensor, val_labels_tensor))

# adapt layer using training sentences
int_vectorize_layer.adapt(train_sentences)

# now here is where the error occurs
int_train_df = train_dataset.map(int_vectorize_text) # ERROR
int_val_df = val_dataset.map(int_vectorize_text)
```

As you can see, an error occurs when we attempt to map the `int_vectorize_text` to the tensorflow dataset. Specifically, I get the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/akagi/Documents/Projects/MLMastery NLP Tutorial/Lesson 5 - Learned Embedding.ipynb Cell 7 in <cell line: 21>()
     19 # Use the map method to apply the int_vectorize_text function to each element of the dataset
     20 int_vectorize_layer.adapt(train_sentences)
---> 21 int_train_df = train_dataset.map(int_vectorize_text)
     22 int_val_df = val_dataset.map(int_vectorize_text)

File ~/Documents/Projects/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py:2294, in DatasetV2.map(self, map_func, num_parallel_calls, deterministic, name)
   2291   if deterministic is not None and not DEBUG_MODE:
   2292     warnings.warn("The `deterministic` argument has no effect unless the "
   2293                   "`num_parallel_calls` argument is specified.")
-> 2294   return MapDataset(self, map_func, preserve_cardinality=True, name=name)
   2295 else:
   2296   return ParallelMapDataset(
   2297       self,
   2298       map_func,
   (...)
   2301       preserve_cardinality=True,
   2302       name=name)

File ~/Documents/Projects/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py:5499, in MapDataset.__init__(self, input_dataset, map_func, use_inter_op_parallelism, preserve_cardinality, use_legacy_function, name)
   5497 self._use_inter_op_parallelism = use_inter_op_parallelism
   5498 self._preserve_cardinality = preserve_cardinality
-> 5499 self._map_func = structured_function.StructuredFunctionWrapper(
...
    '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
    
    Call arguments received by layer 'text_vectorization' (type TextVectorization):
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=<unknown>, dtype=string)
```

Which seems to imply that a `NoneType` is being passed. However, I checked the construction of `train_dataset` and it appears to be correct. Here is what it looks like:

```
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'topology freaking sucks man, what a waste of time!'>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=0>)
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'wow bro you a NLP fan? Tell me more I want to know'>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=1>)
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'you know, I will eventually die'>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=0>)
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'the secret to happiness is to only be depresssed'>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=0>)
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'what is the floor without feet'>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=1>)
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'regicide is permissable only in historical situations'>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=1>)
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'I do not like delivering wehat based products for I am allergic to wheat'>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=0>)
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'Why does he ring the large bell every hour?'>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=0>)
```

Furthermore, if I apply `int_vectorize_text` manually in a loop like so:

```
for x in train_dataset:
    print(int_vectorize_text(x[0], x[1]))
```

No error occurs and I get the desired output. What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reviewing @AloneTogether's clean and more appropriate solution, it appears your issue is stemming from `train_dataset` and `val_dataset` definitions. The documentation for the [tf.data.Dataset.from_generator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator) function recommends that one

> ... use the `output_signature` argument. In this case the output will be assumed to consist of objects with the classes, shapes and types defined by `tf.TypeSpec` objects from `output_signature` argument

As you didn't use the `output_signature` argument, it defaulted to using the deprecated way which uses either the `output_types` argument alone, or together with `output_shapes`. In your case, `output_types` was set to `(tf.string, tf.int32)` but because you left the `output_shapes` argument empty, it defaulted to "unknown".

Later when you go to [map](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#map) the `int_vectorize_text` function, it attempts to check if the input shape rank is greater than 1, however, it receives "shape=<unknown>" which is of type `NoneType` and so the TypeError manifests when comparing with type `int`.

Knowing all this, you can simply add `((), ())` as the output shape in your `from_generator` function call after the output type `(tf.string, tf.int32)`. Hence, replace these lines:

```py
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    generate_data, (tf.string, tf.int32), args=(train_sentences_tensor, train_labels_tensor))

val_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    generate_data, (tf.string, tf.int32), args=(val_sentences_tensor, val_labels_tensor))
```

With:

```py
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    generate_data, output_types=(tf.string, tf.int32), output_shapes=((), ()), args=(train_sentences_tensor, train_labels_tensor))

val_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    generate_data, output_types=(tf.string, tf.int32), output_shapes=((), ()), args=(val_sentences_tensor, val_labels_tensor))
```

Or, the TensorFlow recommended way as @AloneTogether demonstrated:

```py
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    generate_data, output_signature=(
         tf.TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.string),
         tf.TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int32)), args=(train_sentences_tensor, train_labels_tensor))

val_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    generate_data, output_signature=(
         tf.TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.string),
         tf.TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int32)), args=(val_sentences_tensor, val_labels_tensor))
```

I've removed my original solution as I don't believe in propagating code that is suboptimal. Full credit to @AloneTogether for showing how it's supposed to be done. My intent with this edit is to hopefully explain the error and why it occurred so that you and future readers have a better understanding.

Comment: I do not think it is necessary to use `tf.py_function`.

Comment: @AloneTogether If there's another way then please post it, I would appreciate the opportunity to learn something about getting functions to map across datasets

Comment: Sure see answer below.

Comment: @AloneTogether Very nice. I've edited my answer to remove the old solution and complement yours with an explanation. I appreciate you taking the time to post an answer, always good to learn something

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example without `tf.py_function`, as requested by @KyleFHartzenberg:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# 0 = negative
# 1 = positive
documents = [['topology freaking sucks man, what a waste of time!', 0], ['wow bro you a NLP fan? Tell me more I want to know', 1], 
['you know, I will eventually die',0], ['the secret to happiness is to only be depresssed',0], 
['what is the floor without feet', 1], ['regicide is permissable only in historical situations',1],
['I do not like delivering wehat based products for I am allergic to wheat', 0], 
['Why does he ring the large bell every hour?',0],
['Wisdom comes not from experience but from knowing',1], 
['Little is known of the inner workings of the feline mind', 1]]

VOCAB_SIZE = 500 # max amount of vocabulary amongst all documents
MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH = 50 # maximum amount of words/tokens that will be considered in each document
# output mode 'int' will assign unique integer per token, so in our example below, 'topology' is assigned the value
# 19. Notice that these integers are randomly assigned and essentially acts as a hashmap
int_vectorize_layer = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(
    max_tokens=VOCAB_SIZE,
    output_mode='int',
    output_sequence_length = MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,
)

def int_vectorize_text(sentence, label):
  return int_vectorize_layer(sentence), label


def generate_data(sentences, labels):
  for s, l in zip(sentences,labels):
    yield s, l

train_docs = documents[:8]
val_docs = documents[8:]

train_sentences = [d[0] for d in train_docs]
train_labels = [d[1] for d in train_docs]

val_sentences = [d[0] for d in val_docs]
val_labels = [d[1] for d in val_docs]

train_sentences_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(train_sentences)
train_labels_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(train_labels)

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    generate_data, output_signature=(
         tf.TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.string),
         tf.TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int32)), args=(train_sentences_tensor, train_labels_tensor))

# adapt layer using training sentences
int_vectorize_layer.adapt(train_dataset.map(lambda x, y: x))
int_train_df = train_dataset.map(int_vectorize_text)

for x, y in int_train_df:
  print(x, y)
  break
```

```
tf.Tensor(
[19 42 22 34  7 10 17 29 20  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0], shape=(50,), dtype=int64) tf.Tensor(0, shape=(), dtype=int32)
```